# Nameko - Cannot find reference 'config' in '__init__.py'

Tags: python, pytest, integration-testing, nameko

I'm setting up the integration tests in **Nameko** wity **pyTest** . in my `conftest.py` I added the following fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_config(rabbit_config, db_url):
    with config.patch({'DB_URIS': {'service:Base': db_url}}):
        yield
```

But I got this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'nameko'
```

PS: I have `Nameko 2.14.0` installed